# After update Android Soundboard wont play sounds on Galaxy s3

Tags: android, galaxy

```
package com.ccgames.pfsoundboardplus;

import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.ccgames.pfsoundboardplus.R;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class newBoard extends Activity {
int currentPlayingID=-1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


          // import sound files
     @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);






    // play sound files on clicks
    Button s01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01); 
    s01.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote01));
    s01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(1);
            }

    });
    registerForContextMenu(s01);

    Button s02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02); 
    s02.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote02));
    s02.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(2);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s02);

    Button s03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button03); 
    s03.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote03));
    s03.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(3);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s03);

    Button s04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button04); 
    s04.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote04));
    s04.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(4);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s04);

    Button s05 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button05); 
    s05.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote05));
    s05.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(5);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s05);

    Button s06 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button06); 
    s06.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote06));
    s06.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(6);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s06);

    Button s07 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button07); 
    s07.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote07));
    s07.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(7);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s07);

    Button s08 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button08); 
    s08.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote08));
    s08.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(8);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s08);

    Button s09 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button09); 
    s09.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote09));
    s09.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(9);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s09);

    Button s10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10); 
    s10.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote10));
    s10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(10);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s10);

    Button s11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11); 
    s11.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote11));
    s11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(11);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s11);

    Button s12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12); 
    s12.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote12));
    s12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(12);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s12);

    Button s13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13); 
    s13.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote13));
    s13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(13);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s13);

    Button s14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14); 
    s14.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote14));
    s14.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(14);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s14);

    Button s15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button15); 
    s15.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote15));
    s15.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(15);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s15);

    Button s16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button16); 
    s16.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote16));
    s16.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(16);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s16);

    Button s17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17); 
    s17.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote17));
    s17.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(17);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s17);

    Button s18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button18); 
    s18.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote18));
    s18.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(18);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s18);

    Button s19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19); 
    s19.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote19));
    s19.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(19);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s19);

    Button s20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button20); 
    s20.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote20));
    s20.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(20);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s20);

    Button s21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21); 
    s21.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote21));
    s21.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(21);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s21);

    Button s22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button22); 
    s22.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote22));
    s22.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(22);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s22);

    Button s23 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button23); 
    s23.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote23));
    s23.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(23);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s23);

    Button s24 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button24); 
    s24.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote24));
    s24.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(24);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s24);

    Button s25 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button25); 
    s25.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote25));
    s25.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(25);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s25);

    Button s26 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button26); 
    s26.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote26));
    s26.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(26);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s26);

    Button s27 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button27); 
    s27.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote27));
    s27.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(27);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s27);

    Button s28 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button28); 
    s28.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote28));
    s28.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(28);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s28);

    Button s29 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button29); 
    s29.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote29));
    s29.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(29);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s29);

    Button s30 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button30); 
    s30.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote30));
    s30.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(30);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s30);

    Button s31 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button31); 
    s31.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote31));
    s31.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(31);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s31);

    Button s32 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button32); 
    s32.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote32));
    s32.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(32);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s32);

    Button s33 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button33); 
    s33.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote33));
    s33.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(33);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s33);

    Button s34 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button34); 
    s34.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote34));
    s34.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(34);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s34);

    Button s35 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button35); 
    s35.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote35));
    s35.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(35);
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(s35);
    WebView webview;


}
MediaPlayer m=null;
private void playSound(int id){
    stopCurrentPlayer();

    try {
        switch(id){
        case 1:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound01);

            break;
        case 2:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound02);

            break;
        case 3:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound03);

            break;
        case 4:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound04);

            break;
        case 5:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound05);

            break;
        case 6:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound06);

            break;
        case 7:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound07);

            break;
        case 8:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound08);

            break;
        case 9:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound09);

            break;
        case 10:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound10);

            break;
        case 11:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound11);

            break;
        case 12:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound12);

            break;
        case 13:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound13);

            break;
        case 14:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound14);

            break;
        case 15:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound15);

            break;
        case 16:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound16);

            break;
        case 17:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound17);

            break;
        case 18:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound18);

            break;
        case 19:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound19);

            break;
        case 20:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound20);

            break;
        case 21:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound21);

            break;
        case 22:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound22);

            break;
        case 23:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound23);

            break;
        case 24:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound24);

            break;
        case 25:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound25);

            break;

        case 26:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound26);

            break;

        case 27:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound27);

            break;

        case 28:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound28);

            break;

        case 29:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound29);

            break;

        case 30:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound30);

            break;

        case 31:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound31);

            break;

        case 32:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound32);

            break;

        case 33:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound33);

            break;

        case 34:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound34);

            break;

        case 35:
            m=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound35);

            break;
        }
        try {
            m.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        m.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

  }

  private void stopCurrentPlayer(){
    try {
            if(m != null){
                m.stop();
                m.release();
            }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

  }

 // perform save functions on long press
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");  
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone/Notification");    
    }  

    @Override  
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone/Notification"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
    else {return false;}  
  return true;  
}  


// detect which button was clicked, save as a ringtone with strings.xml
public boolean function1(int ressound){  

    //----
          String soundname = "";

           switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button01:
        ressound = R.raw.sound01;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote01));
        break;
        }

           switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button02:
        ressound = R.raw.sound02;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote02));
        break;
        }
           switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button03:
        ressound = R.raw.sound03;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote03));
        break;
        }

       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button04:
        ressound = R.raw.sound04;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote04));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button05:
        ressound = R.raw.sound05;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote05));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button06:
        ressound = R.raw.sound06;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote06));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button07:
        ressound = R.raw.sound07;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote07));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button08:
        ressound = R.raw.sound08;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote08));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button09:
        ressound = R.raw.sound09;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote09));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button10:
        ressound = R.raw.sound10;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote10));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button11:
        ressound = R.raw.sound11;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote11));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button12:
        ressound = R.raw.sound12;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote12));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button13:
        ressound = R.raw.sound13;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote13));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button14:
        ressound = R.raw.sound14;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote14));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button15:
        ressound = R.raw.sound15;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote15));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button16:
        ressound = R.raw.sound16;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote16));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button17:
        ressound = R.raw.sound17;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote17));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button18:
        ressound = R.raw.sound18;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote18));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button19:
        ressound = R.raw.sound19;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote19));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button20:
        ressound = R.raw.sound20;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote20));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button21:
        ressound = R.raw.sound21;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote21));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button22:
        ressound = R.raw.sound22;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote22));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button23:
        ressound = R.raw.sound23;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote23));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button24:
        ressound = R.raw.sound24;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote24));
        break;
        }
       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button25:
        ressound = R.raw.sound25;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote25));
        break;
        }

       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button26:
        ressound = R.raw.sound26;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote26));
        break;
        }

       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button27:
        ressound = R.raw.sound27;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote27));
        break;
        }

       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button28:
        ressound = R.raw.sound28;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote28));
        break;
        }

       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button29:
        ressound = R.raw.sound29;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote29));
        break;
        }

       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button30:
        ressound = R.raw.sound30;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote30));
        break;
        }

       switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button31:
        ressound = R.raw.sound31;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote31));
        break;
        }

   switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button32:
        ressound = R.raw.sound32;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote32));
        break;
        }

   switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button33:
        ressound = R.raw.sound33;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote33));
        break;
        }

   switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button34:
        ressound = R.raw.sound34;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote34));
        break;
        }

   switch(ressound){
        case R.id.button35:
        ressound = R.raw.sound35;
        soundname = (this.getString(R.string.quote35));
        break;
        }

          //and so on and so on.....
          byte[] buffer=null;
           InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
           int size=0;

           try {
           size = fIn.available();
           buffer = new byte[size];
           fIn.read(buffer);
           fIn.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           return false;
           }

           String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
           String filename=soundname+".ogg";

           boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
           if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

           FileOutputStream save;
           try {
           save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
           save.write(buffer);
           save.flush();
           save.close();
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           return false;
           } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           return false;
           }

           sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

           File k = new File(path, filename);

           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundname);
           values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "FRIDAY");
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
           values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

           //Insert it into the database
            this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);


          String i = "Saved as Ringtone.";
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i,
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         return true;


          }

    //----


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        stopCurrentPlayer();

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

}
```

and the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.ccgames.pfsoundboardplus"
  android:versionCode="6"
  android:versionName="1.5"
  android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".newBoard"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:debuggable="false">                 

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>        
     </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
</application>


</manifest>
```

I only Changed the manifest specifically screen layouts and telephony.  And in the Main Activity i only added buttons.  In the Java I added the events that corresponded with the new buttons (simple copy and paste really).the main purpose of the update was to add more sounds.  It works on every other phone I have tested, and I have had a few Customers report in that when they press the buttons no sounds play.  BUT ONLY ON THE GALXY S3  is there something I am missing?

Comment: This could use some serious refactoring..

Comment: Criticism aside any reason it will play on a galaxy tab 2 but not an s3

Comment: When you debug it on the S3, what errors does it give you?

Comment: I see a few weak points, but nothing that would suggest it would fail specifically on an S3 (only). You might want to get some more information from the people that are experiencing this issue.

Comment: It is time for an upgrade for me and I was going to go with a note 2.  Maybe ill get an s3 instead. Getting info out of the customers is like pulling teeth sometimes. But I did ask. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've got a few S3's around here, I don't much like them though. I'd test this for you but 1) I don't feel like getting the ad apis, 2) I don't have the layouts, 3) I don't have the resources :(

Comment: Ha ha thanks for pointing that out this version has no ads forgot to take it out of the manifest.